# Calculate summation from data in input fields by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm starting at learning javascript and I have a problem

here is my html code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Qty1 : <input class="txt" type="number" id="qty1"/>
  </td>
  <td>Value: <input type="text" class="getPrice" id="id1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    Qty2 : <input class="txt" type="number" id="qty2"/>
  </td>
  <td>Value: <input type="text" class="getPrice" id="id2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    Qty3 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty3"/>
  </td>
  <td>Value: <input type="text" class="getPrice" id="id3"></td>
</tr>
<br><br>
<tr>
  <td>Summation of value : </td>
  <td><span id="sums">0</span></td>
</tr>
```

and here is my js code

```
/* get data */
qty1.oninput = function() {
    var inputF1 = document.getElementById("id1");
  inputF1.value = qty1.value*2;
};
qty2.oninput = function() {
    var inputF2 = document.getElementById("id2");
  inputF2.value = qty2.value*3;
};
qty3.oninput = function() {
    var inputF3 = document.getElementById("id3");
  inputF3.value = qty3.value;
};

/* calculate sumation */
$(document).ready(function(){
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".getPrice").each(function() {
    $(this).on('input',function(){
      calculateSum();
    });
  });
  calculateSum();
});

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".getPrice").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sums").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the `Qty` input fields then the summation should be calculated. However, I have to enter values for the `value` input fields for my calculate function works.
How I can fix it? My expected result is that when I input the `qyt` input field it must calculate the summation and return the result.
For example, when I entered 1 in `Qty1` field the summation should be 2 then I entered 3 in `Qty2` the summation should return 11 and so on.
Thank you for your help!

my demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/1c0r6uhd/

Comment: The problem is you are calculating the sum before the value gets updated. To fix this, you need to call calculateSum after inputF1, inputF2, and inputF3 get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to call calculateSum after each value field is updated. Currently, you call it on the input event, which is fired before the actual value has been updated. Here is an example:

```js
$('#qty1').on('input', function() {
  $('#id1').val(this.value * 2).change();
})

$('#qty2').on('input', function() {
  $('#id2').val(this.value * 3).change();
});

$('#qty3').on('input', function() {
  $('#id3').val(this.value).change();
});

$('.getPrice').change(function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".getPrice").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sums").html(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    Qty1 : <input class="txt" type="number" id="qty1"/>
  </td>
  <td>Value: <input type="text" class="getPrice" id="id1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    Qty2 : <input class="txt" type="number" id="qty2"/>
  </td>
  <td>Value: <input type="text" class="getPrice" id="id2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    Qty3 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty3"/>
  </td>
  <td>Value: <input type="text" class="getPrice" id="id3"></td>
</tr>
<br><br>
<tr>
  <td>Summation of value : </td>
  <td><span id="sums">0</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. However, if I have default `value="5"` in `qty` input field, it can not calculate summation immediately. How I can fix it?

Comment: Hi Tung, you will need to trigger the input event when the document loads. Something like this: `$(function() { $('#qty1').trigger('input') })`